# Fastest way to parse a XML file with libxml2?

Tags: c++, parsing, libxml2

Hi is there any "**faster**" way to parse a XML file with libxml2? 
Right now i do it that way following C++ Code:

```
void parse_element_names(xmlNode * a_node, int *calls)
{
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;

    for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) {
      (*calls)++;
      if(xmlStrEqual(xmlCharStrdup("to"),cur_node->name)){
        //printf("node type: <%d>, name <%s>, content: <%s> \n", cur_node->children->type, cur_node->children->name, cur_node->children->content);
        //do something with the content
        parse_element_names(cur_node->children->children,calls);
        }
      else if(xmlStrEqual(xmlCharStrdup("from"),cur_node->name)) {
        //printf("node type: <%d>, name <%s>, content: <%s> \n", cur_node->children->type, cur_node->children->name, cur_node->children->content);
        //do something with the content
        parse_element_names(cur_node->children->children,calls);
        }
      else if(xmlStrEqual(xmlCharStrdup("note"),cur_node->name)) {
        //printf("node type: <%d>, name <%s>, content: <%s> \n", cur_node->children->type, cur_node->children->name, cur_node->children->content);
        //do something with the content
        parse_element_names(cur_node->children->children,calls);
        }
        .
        .
        .
        //about 100 more node names comming
      else{
        parse_element_names(cur_node->children,calls);
      }
    }

}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 

    xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
    xmlNode *root_element = NULL;

    if (argc != 2)
        return(1);

    /*parse the file and get the DOM */
    doc = xmlReadFile(argv[1], NULL, XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS);

    if (doc == NULL) {
        printf("error: could not parse file %s\n", argv[1]);
    }
    int calls = 0;
    /*Get the root element node */
    root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
    parse_element_names(root_element,&calls);

    /*free the document */
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);

    xmlCleanupParser();

    return 0;
}
```

Is it really the fastest way? Or is there any better/faster solution which you can advice me?

Thank you

Comment: Using a hash table should be faster if you have a lot of node names. Note that the way you use `xmlCharStrdup` leaks memory. Simply cast a string literal to `const xmlChar *` instead. Dereferencing `children` twice also looks wrong to me.

Answer (score 2):

`xmlReadFile` et al. are based on libxml2's [SAX parser interface](http://www.xmlsoft.org/interface.html) (actually, the [SAX2 interface](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-SAX2.html)), so it's generally faster to use your own SAX parser if you don't need the resulting `xmlDoc`.

If you have to distinguish between many different element names like in your example, the fastest approach is usually to create separate functions for every type of node and use a hash table to lookup these functions.